# bibtexparser - pyparsing.ParseException: Expected end of text

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing, bibtex

I'm using `bibtexparser` to parse a bibtex file.

```
import bibtexparser
with open('MetaGJK12842.bib','r') as bibfile:
    bibdata = bibtexparser.load(bibfile)
```

While parsing I get the error message:

> Could not parse properly, starting at
>
> ```
> @article{Frenn:EvidenceBasedNursing:1999,
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyparsing.py", line 3183, in parseImpl
> raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
> pyparsing.ParseException: Expected end of text (at char 5773750), 
> (line:47478, col:1)`
> ```

The line refers to the following bibtex entry:

```
@article{Frenn:EvidenceBasedNursing:1999,
    author = {Frenn, M.},
    title = {A Mediterranean type diet reduced all cause and cardiac mortality after a first myocardial infarction [commentary on de Lorgeril M, Salen P, Martin JL, et al. Mediterranean dietary pattern in a randomized trial: prolonged survival and possible reduced cancer rate. ARCH INTERN MED 1998;158:1181-7]},
    journal = {Evidence Based Nursing},
    uuid = {15A66A61-0343-475A-8700-F311B08BB2BC},
    volume = {2},
    number = {2},
    pages = {48-48},
    address = {College of Nursing, Marquette University, Milwaukee, WI},
    year = {1999},
    ISSN = {1367-6539},
    url = {},
    keywords = {Treatment Outcomes;Mediterranean Diet;Mortality;France;Neoplasms -- Prevention and Control;Phase One Excluded - No Assessment of Vegetable as DV;Female;Phase One - Reviewed by Hao;Myocardial Infarction -- Diet Therapy;Diet, Fat-Restricted;Phase One Excluded - No Fruit or Vegetable Study;Phase One Excluded - No Assessment of Fruit as DV;Male;Clinical Trials},
    tags = {Phase One Excluded - No Assessment of Vegetable as DV;Phase One Excluded - No Fruit or Vegetable Study;Phase One - Reviewed by Hao;Phase One Excluded - No Assessment of Fruit as DV},
    accession_num = {2000008864. Language: English. Entry Date: 20000201. Revision Date: 20130524. Publication Type: journal article},
    remote_database_name = {rzh},
    source_app = {EndNote},
    EndNote_reference_number = {4413},
    Secondary_title = {Evidence Based Nursing},
    Citation_identifier = {Frenn 1999a},
    remote_database_provider = {EBSCOhost},
    publicationStatus = {Unknown},
    abstract = {Question: text.},
    notes = {(0) abstract; commentary. Journal Subset: Core Nursing; Europe; Nursing; Peer Reviewed; UK \& Ireland. No. of Refs: 1 ref. NLM UID: 9815947.}
}
```

What is wrong with this entry?

Comment: What happens when you try `@ARTICLE` instead of `@article`?

Comment: All other entries start with `@article` and don't raise exceptions. Changing it manually to `@ARTICLE`in the bibtex file gave the same error.

Comment: Then I don't know what might be the case. Testing with https://github.com/pezmc/biblatex-check produced an error with `@article`, while `@ARTICLE` was accepted. If both are rejected by `bibtexparser`, then it could be a bug in said lib.

Comment: I copied that item into its own file called 'lisadk.txt' then executed `one_record = bibtexparser.load(bibfile)`. It worked! Apparently their is a flaw in the input file somewhere before this item. I would try finding it by attempting to load 1/2 of the records prior to this one, then 3/4, then 7/8 until I had identified a culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue has been addressed and resolved in the project repository (see [Issue 147](https://github.com/sciunto-org/python-bibtexparser/issues/147))

Until the next release, installing the library from the git repository can serve as a temporary fix.

`pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/sciunto-org/python-bibtexparser.git@master`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and found an entry near the line mentioned in the error that had a line like this

```
...
year = {1959},
month =
}
```

When I removed the null month item it parsed for me.

Comment: Yes it turned out that the entry above this one (and 7 others) had a similar problem like yours, which I manually deleted. Makes me wonder if there is a more efficient solution for this, when for example I come across a significantly larger amount of wrong entries..